(Xcode 15.4) Failure Reason: The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace)
I have developed an application using flutter and trying to build IOS application for the same and When I am trying to install the application on my device, application is crashing while launch.
The request to open "com.example.com" failed.
Domain: IDELaunchCoreDevice

Code: 0
User Info: {
   DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-07-17 03:27:19 +0000";
   IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchCoreDeviceWorker;
}```


The request to open "com.example.com" failed.
```Domain: IDELaunchCoreDevice
Code: 0
User Info: {
   IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchCoreDeviceWorker;
}```


The application failed to launch.
Domain: com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError
Code: 10002
```User Info: {
   BundleIdentifier = "com.example.com";
}```


The request to open "com.example.com" failed.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace).
```User Info: {
   BSErrorCodeDescription = RequestDenied;
   FBSOpenApplicationRequestID = 0x9523;
}```


The operation couldn’t be completed. The process failed to launch.
Domain: FBProcessExit
Code: 64
Failure Reason: The process failed to launch.
```User Info: {
   BSErrorCodeDescription = "launch-failed";
}

The operation couldn’t be completed. Launch failed.
Domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain
Code: 5
Failure Reason: Launch failed.
Launchd job spawn failed
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 85
Failure Reason: Bad executable (or shared library)
   "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
   "device_model" = "iPhone13,2";
   "device_osBuild" = "17.5.1 (21F90)";
   "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
   "dvt_coredevice_version" = "355.28";
   "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.120.2";
   "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
   "launchSession_state" = 1;
   "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
   "operation_duration_ms" = 2790;
   "operation_errorCode" = 0;
   "operation_errorDomain" = IDELaunchCoreDevice;
   "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchCoreDeviceWorker;
   "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
   "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
   "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
   "param_debugger_type" = 3;
   "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
   "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
   "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
   "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
   "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
   "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
   "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
   "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
   "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
   "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
   "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
   "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
   "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
   "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
   "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
   "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
   "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
   "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
   "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
   "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
   "param_install_style" = 0;
   "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
   "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
   "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
   "param_launcher_style" = 99;
   "param_launcher_substyle" = 8192;
   "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
   "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
   "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
   "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
   "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
   "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
   "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos17.5";
   "sdk_osVersion" = "17.5";
   "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}```

System Information

macOS Version 14.5 (Build 23F79)
Xcode 15.4 (22622) (Build 15F31d)
Timestamp: 2024-07-17T08:57:19+05:30

I tried Installing rosetta running this command on the Terminal:
softwareupdate --install-rosetta

also tried uninstall and install of XCode.


Any luck? Facing the same issue...
